# Relativistic addition of velocities of spaceships

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, velocity

If Spaceship 1 is traveling at speed $.5c$ relative to Earth, and Spaceship 2 is traveling at speed $.3c$ relative to Earth in the same direction, what does Spaceship 2 see Spaceship 1's speed as?

I don't think it is quite as simple as $.5c-.3c = .2c$.

Comment: Your thinking, as far as it goes, is correct.  However, the relativistic velocity addition formula is *so* well known and *so* easy to find (e.g., http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/relativ/einvel2.html), *I simply cannot imagine any serious student of physics asking this question here*.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri To be fair it was asked by 'Fool'.

Comment: What makes you think I know physics? Beginners have to start somewhere!

Comment: @Fool, as I wrote *"I cannot imagine any **serious** student of physics asking this question here"*.  What I think you know about physics is *irrelevant*.

Comment: Okay, but judging from the intention it seemed like you were addressing me. Thx for the post though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you are correct, that it is not quite as simple as that.

Have you studied Special Relativity (SR) yet?

One of the most fundamental ideas is the limiting speed of light. Nothing moves faster than c, and this means that velocities must add differently.

Think of the reverse, if you were on the rocket-ship traveling at $0.5c$ and shot a laser-beam at $c$, you certainly won't get the laser traveling at $1.5c$!

See here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_velocities#Composition_of_velocities

So, we need 
$$ u' = \frac{u-v}{1- \frac{uv}{c^2}}$$

In our case, we get

$$ u' = \frac{0.5c-0.3c}{1- \frac{0.5c \times 0.3c}{c^2}} = \frac{0.2c}{1-0.15} = 0.235c$$