# Universal speed limit

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

> Is there any reason the universe has  matter not being able to exceed the speed of light, or why there is a speed limit in the first place?

I know why it can't, meaning the basic physics of it. I am just wondering if the reason why the universe  is like this is or the benefit of it known.

I know this might be too philosophical, but I am just wondering.

Comment: See my or Trimok's answer here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/128161/

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about philosophy of science, and not physics as such. The question [Why does the universe follow scientific laws?](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/14352/why-does-the-universe-obey-scientific-laws) has been asked at [philosophy.SE] a while ago.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is so special about speed of light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/80365/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One aspect that comes to my mind is the concept of **causality**. Superluminal propagation would allow for a violation of this principle, creating various paradoxical phenomena.

Comment: This would violate causality only if Lorentz transformationas are correct. With Galileo's transformations, it will not violate causality.

Comment: @Anixx Since the speed of light as an upper limit is a concept from special relativity, which contains Lorentz transformations within its mathematical framework, I do not see how your statement is relevant.

Comment: speed higher than speed of light violates causality only in special relativity. So it is special relativity that limits speed of light, not causality. If special relativity were wrong, speed of higher than light would not violate causality.