# Time and velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, speed-of-light, velocity, inertial-frames

Suppose two cars are traveling at a velocity of $c/2$ ($c$=speed of light) in two straight lines parallel to each other but in opposite direction in vacuum.  Then what will a person sitting in one of those cars see when they approach each other?

Comment: Possible duplicates: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131589/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

She will feel motionless, seeing the other car approach with the [combined velocity of the two cars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_relativity):
$$v_\mathrm{tot} = \frac{v_\mathrm{\scriptsize{1}} + v_\mathrm{\scriptsize{2}}}{1 + v_\mathrm{\scriptsize{1}} v_\mathrm{\scriptsize{2}}/c^2} = 0.8c,$$
with all the usual implications of observing something moving at $0.8c^\dagger$.

---

$^\dagger$<sub>E.g. an epic car crash: The kinetic energy of an oncoming car of 1 ton is equivalent to 2 million Nagasaki bombs.</sub>