# Can an inertial frame observe another frame moving faster than $c$?

Tags: special-relativity, inertial-frames, observers, faster-than-light

Why is it impossible to observe someone moving faster than the speed of light?
Suppose there is a frame A. frame A can observe something moving at the the speed $c/2$ right? So suppose there’s two other frame B,C moving in opposite direction. Both can have a speed of $c/2$ as measured by frame A. It doesn’t contradict any law. But according to frame B, frame A is moving at the speed c/2 and frame C is moving at speed c. What’ll happen then? I’m sure missing something but can’t figure out what.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does this count as moving faster than light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/131589/)